# Querying the same column twice in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having problems trying to select the student's name and also his professor's name in the same row.

TABLE USERS

```
ID --- NAME
```

TABLE RESEARCHES

```
STUDENT_ID (FK) --- PROFESSOR_ID (FK)
     referencing USERS
```

Like I said above, I want to select both names in the same row.
Any suggestion?

In addition, there's an optional field in the table RESEARCHES called AUX_PROFESSOR, and if it's set, I'll need to select his name also. How can I do that?

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: `... STUDENT_ID references USERS(id) , ...`

Comment: I'm using postgres. I'm kind of new in this area, but I thought that both were similar.. I don't know if there is a huge query difference between them.

Comment: @user3260711 . . . Can you show sample data and desired results?

Comment: I didn't gete any results because I had no idea how to try it, but I'll add the result I want.. Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple joins.  The following will get the two names on one row:

```
select s.name as student_name, p.name as professor_name
from users s join
     researches r
     on s.id = r.student_id
     users p
     on p.id = r.professor_id;
```

If you then have one or two professors, you can do something like:

```
select s.name as student_name,
       max(p.name) as professor1_name,
       (case when min(p.name) <> max(p.name) then min(p.name) end) as professor2_name
     researches r
     on s.id = r.student_id
     users p
     on p.id = r.professor_id
group by s.name;
```

You don't say how to distinguish between the two types of professor in the data, so this just lists the two names.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how do you know all these things? Hehehe You're a genious. I didn't understand the third line  (case when ..   I'd like to list the second professor if his column value is different from NULL.. otherwise I don't need to have his name.

Comment: @user3260711 . . . Lots of experience working with both people and data.

Comment: +1 to Gordon for the effort without the answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to alias the columns in the resultset.

```
SELECT  s.Name AS StudentName,
        p.Name AS ProfessorName
[...]
```